# Downloading PDF file from browser

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, downloading, pdf

I have been trying to download a PDF file from my Samsung Galaxy 10.1, 32G, Wi-Fi Tab.
When I click on the download icon to check on it,it shows "Download in progress".
A one page file, for instance, will take FOREVER then I get "Download failed".This happens again and again.

Very frustrating! I would then like to transfer the file to e-book to read at a later date.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you open pdf files and doc files off your emails so u can read plans

Answer (score 2):

Try with another browser, like the Android stock browser or Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Dolphin browser (which you should be using anyways), there is an add-on called MyPDF (available in Google Play). Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar trouble.  I went into the Settings for Google Drive (which I guess is my default reader even though I have Adobe Reader downloaded?).  Under Data Usage, I de-selected "Transfer files only over wifi."  Don't know for sure if this will help others, but seems to have worked for me.